# Using mongodb with asp.net core 2.1 identity

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I started an asp.net core 2.1 project using the built-in Visual C# > Web > .NET Core > ASP.NET Core Web Application (Model-View-Controller) template (with authentication as individual accounts). I'm trying to find a step-by-step to convert this project to use a MongoDB db instead of MS-SQL. I already have APIs set up with CRUD operations interacting with the MongoDB just fine, I just need to figure out a way to convert the identity portions over to using MongoDB as well.

Are there any walkthroughs, step-by-step instructions anywhere I can use to convert my database used over to MongoDB? I've found snippets and older instructions here and there made by someone who didn't seem sure they were doing everything right. I only need 2 simple roles (admin & user) and can handle the authorization part once they are logged in on what they can and can't access, I just need help with the authentication part I think?

TIA!

Mythprod

Comment: Did you already found some answer concerning your question. I am also interested in it.

Comment: I never found any documentation on how the pieces fit together but this link helped: [link](https://www.matheus.ro/2018/03/05/getting-started-mongodb-using-asp-net-core-2-web-api/).

I've now got a full api and web app using a mongodb db